# How to put a research department of a university or an internship in the acknowledgments?

Tags: publications, internship, acknowledgement

How can I put a research department of a university or an internship awarded into the acknowledgments section of a research paper?

Comment: Do you mean how to acknowledge the department where you interned?

Comment: @Spark, yes it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply write

> this work has been conducted while Alex was visiting XXXXXX